# add new thread into python queue

Tags: python, multithreading, queue

I need to create a queue of N (for instance 8) threads and add new thread asap any one from the queue is done.

for now, I find out how to run 8 threads simultaneously and then 8 simultaneously again and so on.

what I want is run 8 simultaneously and then one more after any from 8 is done and one more after any of 8 is done again and so on

Comment: Have a look at `threading.semaphore()`, https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#semaphore-objects

Comment: I woud be greatful for working solution. the thread could be anything - like
subprocess.Popen(['ls'])

Comment: Can you show an example of your code?

Comment: Rethink your Approach, start N Threads run forever, feed the Threads using a Queue with Tasks.

Comment: I am good with any approach. could you illustrate with the code?